# Use Razor to render a multiple file Input

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm looking to render a multiple file input using the razor html keyword.

So far I have

```
 @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
```

Which renders as

```
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" value>
```

I want to render it as

```
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" multiple>
```

I'm sure this is simple but after a fair amount of googling I haven't been able to find anything. Thank you for your time/help!

Comment: `new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
@Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple" })
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<input id="file" multiple="multiple" name="file" type="file" value="">
```

Comment: does the multiple attribute have to have a value? If so, why? If not, how? Thanks!

Comment: it's not necessary to value you can leave it as empty we just use value to make things simple and more readable. if you want you can use empty